# Python to ruby regex search conversion

Tags: regex

I have a simple python regex `re.search('<span[\w\W]*?>Members[\w\W]*?([\w\W]*?)</span>', str)`. I'd like to do the same in ruby.

From the docs, it appears that [match](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#method-i-match) should work. However when I try

`/<span[\w\W]*?>Members[\w\W]*?([\w\W]*?)</span>/.match(str)` I get a syntax error.

I know this is something obvious but would love some help. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `/` which is inside closing tag of `</span>`

```
/<span[\w\W]*?>Members[\w\W]*?([\w\W]*?)<\/span>/.match(str)
//                                       ^^
```

otherwise this will be considered as end of regex

and you can use `.*?` where `.` mean capture anything except line break

```
/<span.*?>Members.*?(.*?)<\/span>/.match(str)
```

Comment: thanks. that works! is there a ruby equivalent of `search`? Don't see one for ruby and match doesn't work the same

Comment: you can use [scan](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/scan), and glad that I could help!

Comment: and you can use `.*?` instead of `[\w\W]*?` `.` mean capture anything

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of slashes to match, try `%r` notation:

```
%r{<span[\w\W]*?>Members[\w\W]*?([\w\W]*?)</span>}.match(str)
```